# How to center background image in cool kitten vertical parallax

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, vertical-scrolling

I am using cool kitten vertical parallax framework.
When i resized the window or view in mobile, the background image is not centered.

I tried `background-position: center;`
Also `background-size:cover;`

But it turns out the js overwrites position to something dynamic like -

```
 element.style {
         background-position: 25px 172px;
    }
```

Since it's vertical parallax, I just want the Y co ordinate to change and X to be constant, so as the image is centered on the x axis, no matter on which device it is viewed.

Update 1:

I centered the image using `background-position-x: center !important;`
but now it's causing a gap on mobile version.

demo link - http://goo.gl/bMHA81
when viewed in mobile, looks like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJaW4.png
i am looking to eliminate that orange gap.

Comment: add parent div and add style to it div{ margin:0px auto; }.

Comment: that didn't work. I am looking to make the background image center (even if left and right part is trimmed when window is resized). but when i resize window from right to left, the center of image remains at right side and image is floating from the left most point.

Comment: can you post a demo link..

Comment: added links and updates